# Control character encoding in the 'rio' package?

Tags: r, import, encoding, character-encoding, r-rio

My txt table looks like this:

```
morče   kanár   malý pes
morče   potkan  rybičky
želva   rybičky střední pes
kočka   papoušek    želva
```

It is encoded in UTF-8 and stored in file `mazlicci.txt`. When I try

```
library(rio)
import("mazlicci.txt")
```

the character encoding is broken.

How can I control character encoding in the `rio` package? The `encoding` argument in `import` knows only three charsets: `UTF-8`, `unknown`, and `Latin-1`. The `UTF-8` option does not remedy the problem. (Nor the other ones, expectedly.) I am working on Windows 7, `R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10) -- "Very Secure Dishes", Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)`,Czech locale (cp1250). I experience no encoding problems with UTF-8 encoded files using the basic R importing functions.

Comment: You are on windows, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the encoding in the `import` function:

```
library(rio)
import("mazlicci.txt", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Comment: And what happens when you import a bunch of files via lapply? Example: mylist <- lapply(excel_files_list, rio::import(encoding = "UCS-2LE"))          I get an error :  Error in grepl("^http.*://", file) : 
  argument "file" is missing, with no default

Comment: Your use of lapply is wrong. it should look something like: lapply(excel_files_list, rio::import, encoding = "UCS-2LE"). Please see ?lapply for more details.